# zip argument #1 must support iteration while evaluating and obtain single dict that didn't merged python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, odoo-11

Hi I want to ask 2 question between nested dict and zip argument. First question is I have a code that merged 2 dict into one. It stacks between each other. What I want is the value that didn't stack. It means name or id aren't same value. How can I achive this?

DICT

```
folder_1 = {'folders': [
{'id': 124, 'name': 'Leads', 'totalBlacklisted': 0, 'uniqueSubscribers': 0, 'totalSubscribers': 0}, 
{'id': 123, 'name': 'Alumni', 'totalBlacklisted': 0, 'uniqueSubscribers': 0, 'totalSubscribers': 0}, 
]}

data = {'folders':[{'id': 124,'name':'Leads'}, {'id': 121,'name': 'Member'},{'id':123,'name':'Alumni'}]}
```

RESULT

```
z = {'folders':[ {'id': 121,'name': 'Member'}]}
```

Second question is when I try my python code from JSON dict, I got an error in zip. I already imported the tools and JSON dict are the code above(folder dict). I want only 2 loops between `for` function. Please help.

PYTHON CODE

```
data_list_1 = ['New','Idle','Appointment No Show','SNC']
folder = {"folders":[{"id":42, "name":"Ninja_Form"},{"id":29,"name":"Prestashop"}]}

for folder_cr_list_1, data_list_leads_1 in zip(folder.get("folders"), data_list_1):
                    ids_1 = folder_cr_list_1['id']
                    name_1 = data_list_leads_1
                    print (ids_1,name_1)
```

Comment: The code you provided is not runnable, please provide a complete, minimal and runnable, example

Comment: Ok i already edited it. It should work fine now. I tried in `trinket` it is working successfully. But when I run, it comes out error in zip.

Comment: I found what went wrong. The dict of `folder.get("folders")` isn't like what i post. It only display the id. There is no get because the result is from post to the external.

Comment: So the question is solved?

Comment: Yes it was solved. Sorry for my late reply, been busy with this project. I uses API for this, it is my first time doing this.